# Passing variables into an included PHP file to be used as MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, variables, include

I'm having trouble passing two variables into an included file.

Viewable page:

```
<?php

$sqlCount = "This is a working MySQL query.";
$sqlQuery = "This is also a working MySQL query.";

include("include.php");

?>
```

include.php:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query($sqlCount, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
//$result populates variables to be used in second portion of code
//don't need $result anymore

$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
//rest of my code

?>
```

The code works in the viewable PHP page when I don't include it. It also works when I move $sqlCount and $sqlQuery into include.php.

The only real solution I've been able to find was to declare them as global variables, but when I tried it didn't do anything.

*Edit: I figured it out. $sqlQuery had variables inside the query that weren't being created until inside the include.php file.*

Comment: So what is happening, exactly? You say it doesn't work, but what error do you get?

Comment: @Hamish It's an undefined variable error.

Comment: From the sounds of it, those variables might not be in scope. There are a number of reason this could be. Is the included file part of an AJAX function? What's the depth of `$result` in the included file? Is `$result` in a function that might be parsed at runtime? I'd try `var_dump()`ing those variables at the very beginning of that included file.

Comment: @jaypea07 Out out curiosity, try using... `include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/include.php");`

Comment: @showerhead There's no AJAX involved. The first $result is used in mysql_fetch_row(), the second is used in mysql_fetch_assoc().

Comment: Ok about AJAX, but as to the rest, that's not what I meant. If `$result` was set in an if statement and that statement was the only thing on the page, that statement would be at base depth and `$result` would be at one. What is `$result`'s depth in your program? Does changing its depth matter? Is `$result` **set** in a function that is parsed at runtime before other variables are loaded? Could it be that you are somehow changing these variables before setting `$result`? The full code is not here so it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach, in my point of view would be rewriting the code in "include.php" as a function that you can then call from your "viewable page":

include.php

```
<?php
function included_function($sql_count, $sql_query)
{
    $result = mysql_query($sql_count, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
    //$result populates variables to be used in second portion of code
    //don't need $result anymore

    $result = mysql_query($sql_query, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
    //rest of my code
}
?>
```

"viewable page"

```
<?php
include("include.php");

$sqlCount = "This is a working MySQL query.";
$sqlQuery = "This is also a working MySQL query.";

included_function($sqlCount, $sqlQuery);

?>
```

Comment: This is not actually true. The [PHP manual](http://php.net/include) says: "When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope."

Comment: My bad, thanks for pointing it out, I'll fix my answer right away

Answer (score 0):

did you try

include.php:

```
<?php

echo $sqlCount; die();   // just to be sure you have what you expect?
$result = mysql_query($sqlCount, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
```